# Find key by value in array with array conversion

Tags: javascript

I have a simple input field with id="autocomplete-input" and a button with id="searchButton". I then use a PHP array with key value pairs such that you can type in a value in the input field and then find the correct key for that value. I am using javascript for this so I also need to convert the PHP array into javascript. Please see my code below:

```
  <nav>
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
      <div class="input-field center-align">
        <input type="text" class="autocomplete" name="search" id="autocomplete-input" placeholder="Search.." />
        <button class="icon" id="searchButton"></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <?php
    $testArray = array (
      'yellow' => 'banana',
      'red' => 'apple',
      'green' => 'pear'
    );
  ?>

  $('document').ready(function(){
      $('#searchButton').click(function(){
          var compSearch = document.getElementById('autocomplete-input').value;
          var tempArray = <?php echo json_encode($testArray); ?>;
          var key = search(compSearch, tempArray);
          document.getElementById("autocomplete-input").value = (key);
      })
      $('#searchButton').keypress(function(e){
          if(e.which == 13){ //Enter key pressed
              $('#searchButton').click(); //Trigger search button click event
          }
      });
  });

  function search(nameKey, myArray){
      for (var i=0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
          if (myArray[i].name === nameKey) {
            return myArray[i];
          }
      }
  }
```

No matter what is input I only get "undefined" returned upon click of searchButton. I am not sure if this is the 'search' function that is not working properly - I am thinking that the json_encode of $testArray might also cause issues? I much appreciate any help.

Comment: This is unlikely to be a PHP problem, edit your question to include the code as it appears in the page.

Comment: The JSONed `$testArray` is not a JS array, it's a JS object, hence the `for.. i` loop is never entered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tempArray` will not be an array(*) but a plain object, like this:

```
{
  yellow: 'banana',
  red: 'apple',
  green: 'pear'
}
```

<sup>* Only PHP arrays that are *indexed* arrays (starting from index 0 and without gaps) translate to JS arrays. Otherwise they translate to plain objects.</sup>

So `search` should look like this one liner:

```
return myArray[nameKey];
```

... but maybe choose a better variable name, as it is not an array.